# Class::DBI, Class::DBI::AbstractSearch, and Oracle to_date

Tags: perl

I'm trying to produce the following SQL using CDBI:

```
select * from mytable
where ref = "foo"
  and to_date(received_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') < to_date('01-04-2011', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

The closest syntax I can think of is:

```
mycdbi->search_where({
    ref           => 'foo',
    received_date => { '<' => ["to_date(?, 'DD-MM-YYYY')", '01-04-2011']  }
});
```

However that's not converting the column *mytable.received_date* using Oracle function *to_date*.

So what's the correct way to do it?

Ps: please don't say use DBIC as the code needs to stay in CDBI.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might be easiest to just use [`retrieve_from_sql`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-DBI/lib/Class/DBI.pm#retrieve_from_sql) and do it by hand:

```
my @things = mycdbi->retrieve_from_sql(qq{
        ref = 'foo'
    AND to_date(received_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') < to_date('01-04-2011', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
});
```

I usually end up pushing the ORMs out of the way for any instantiation more complicated than `my $thing = Thing->retrieve(x)`, I already know SQL so I don't need to learn yet another API that tries to implement SQL and usually does so rather poorly.